# Run Ruby script in the background

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that I need to have running all the time in my Linux box. I tried `nohup ruby ruby.rb&` but it seems it doesn't work.

How can I have the script running in background?

Comment: No. But when I do "nohup" I imagine I should see the result in the output file and I don't. I just want to make sure it is running.

Comment: Well when you originally run the command with the & do you get a PID?

Comment: Yes, ~# nohup ruby unread_mail.rb &
[4] 15859

Comment: okay, so you can run `ps -a` and verify whether the process is running. The only reason it wouldn't be is that the script itself is terminating

Comment: Strange, I have same issue. Why does Ruby not output while node.js script does? I use nohup with output redirection same way for both. Ruby runs fine without nohup.

Comment: This explains my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529986/possible-i-o-sync-issue-with-ruby-script-under-nohup

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have a look at `screen` which is a command-line utility. Start it with

```
screen
```

You will get a new shell which is detached. Start your script there with

```
ruby whatever.rb
```

And watch it run. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and you should be back at your original shell. You can leave the ssh session now, and the script will continue running. At a later time, login to your box and type

```
screen -r
```

and you should be back to the detached shell.

If you use screen more than once, you will have to select the screen session by pid which is not so comfortable. To simplify, you can do

```
screen -S worker
```

to start the session and

```
screen -r worker
```

to resume it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs:

```
fork do
  Process.setsid
  sleep 5
  puts "In daemon"
end
puts "In control script"
```

In real life you will have to reopen STDOUT/STDERR.